# jQuery templating to display JSON data into formatted HTML

Tags: jquery, json

I was having difficulty displaying some json data with use of query template:

Here is my code:

This is the json:

```
{
    "title": "The ppt presenation",
    "date_created": "9242010",
    "last_modified": "9242011",
    "author": "Mistic Frenzies",
    "slides": [
        {
            "Slide": "1",
            "header": "sdfsdf",
            "src": "ghkkgh.jpg",
            "Content": [
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                },
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                },
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                },
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                },
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Slide": "2",
            "header": "sdfsdf",
            "src": null,
            "Content": [
             {
                    "bullet": ""
                },
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                },
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                },
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                },
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Slide": 3,
            "header": "dsggd",
            "src": "sdfsdf.jpg",
            "Content": [
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                },
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                },
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                },
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                },
                {
                    "bullet": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>

<script id="ititemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <h2>${title}</h2>
    <li>${author}</li>
        {{each slides}}
            <h3>${header}</h3>
            <li>${slide}</li>
            <ol>
                {{each Content}}
                    <li style="background-color:#98FB98;">${bullet}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ol>
        {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#powerpoint').click(function() {
            //var jsonloc = "ppt.json";
            $.getJSON('ppt.json',function(info){
                $('#header').empty();
                $('#ititemplate').tmpl(info).appendTo('#header');                       
            });                                 
        }); 
    });

</script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="#" id="powerpoint">Powerpoint</a>
<div id="header">
</div>
</body>
```

So, I am not sure what is wrong. When I click on the html link to display the data, nothing appears. I am wondering if the template I created is faulty. Any suggestions?

Comment: do you see any errors in logs?

Comment: template html structure is invalid `H2`or `H3` or `OL` can not be siblings of `LI`

Comment: Can you check for any javascript errors in the console, It seems to be working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/P3JKY/

Comment: the console does not give me any script errors... Does anyone see anything wrong with the Javascript?

Comment: I fixed the html template format.

Answer (score 0):

code seems fine. i think getJSON taking longer to return info and your code is executing appendTo command before it finishes. you can use deferred in jquery (i.e. when....then) or use $.ajax and use its success method to template over info like below:

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ppt.json',
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (info) {
                 $('#header').empty();
                $('#ititemplate').tmpl(info).appendTo('#header');   
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //failure function goes here..
            }
        });
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I want to try to get this to work without ajax. So I tried the deferring: $.when($.getJSON('intrislam.json') ).then(function(info){